# How to reduce the logservice RPC's in google app engine backends

Tags: google-app-engine, rpc, backend

[image]

above is the image of appstats of a single GET request to my app,

[image]

this image shows the RPC traces of a single logservice RPC

do the number of loservice calls effect the app negatively, for 5 urlfetch RPC's there are around 80 logsservice RPC's while using a backend.  i dont know the reason for these logservice rpc calls, how do i reduce the number of logservice RPC's,

in the backends documentation there is limited documentation about logservice

```
logservice.flush()
```

how do i contril log flushing in backends, instead of random logservice calls
thanks

Comment: Is that the complete stacktrace of the flush call? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @nick yes it is, let me add another screenshot expanding all the calls

Comment: http://imgur.com/tQuB5  http://imgur.com/0EaPk

Comment: also,how do i configure auto_flush. in the earlier screenshots i didnot fiddle with the logging service in my code. may be by configuring auto_flush i can reduce the calls? thanks

Comment: The gap you've highlighted is everything that isn't RPC calls - your code doing what it does, in short. I'll get back to you on the logservice setup in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure log flushing by changing some of the values set by the logservice API, documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/logserviceapi.html) ([source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice.py)). The default is to flush every 10 seconds, 1024 bytes, or 20 lines, whichever comes first. You can disable any of them independently, or disable the whole autoflush process.

To disable autoflush entirely:

```
from google.appengine.api import logservice
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_ENABLED = False

# When you want to flush manually, do this
logservice.flush()
```

to flush every 20 lines, with no limit on time or bytes:

```
from google.appengine.api import logservice
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_EVERY_SECONDS = None
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_EVERY_BYTES = None
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_EVERY_LINES 20 # The default, but set here for clarity
```

Don't be too stingy with log flushing - as you observe, the RPCs are very fast, and not having your logs flushed can be a real pain when you need to debug something.

Comment: but the thing is these flush calls are so random, and it seems like my output is changing based on whether the logs are flushed or not

Comment: @RemotePath Sorry, I don't understand - what makes you think they're random as opposed to based on the above logic, and how does your output change? It sounds like you're not describing the complete problem.

Comment: i dont get the concept of logging, how are they useful, and why do i have to deal with them only in case of backends, how are they use ful in debugging? thanks nick

Comment: after updating my backend i had to restart the backend for it to take into effect

Comment: @RemotePath Logging allows you to see what's happening in your code in case something goes wrong - you can document what occurs as it occurs. Since you can't attach an interactive debugger to a process in production, this is the only way to capture information about how you generated a result. You don't _have_ to deal with it for a backend, but because they run indefinitely, there needs to be some way to output log entries before the process completes, hence this API. If you're only sending it short-lived requests and want it to behave like a frontend, turn off log flushing entirely.